# Функция просмотра содержимого виджета Qt

Tags: qt

Подскажите, есть ли функция для просмотра списка содержимого виджета Qt? Например QCheckBox состоит из indicator и label. Можно ли как-то просмотреть/считать текущий стиль виджета, его отступы и цвета?

Comment: Как мне кажется - немного не корректно поставлен вопрос. содержимое и стили- разные вещи. Стили, если я правильно понимаю - посмотри [тут] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45436994/obtain-inherited-stylesheet-for-a-qwidget-from-parents-above-it) а содержимое - [children()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qobject.html#children)

Comment: Где-то я видел функцию, может в питоне, где обращаешься к элементу а он возвращает список то ли элементов которые в нем есть то ли список параметров которые есть внутри него... не помню к сожалению что это было...